# MySQL Help, Duplicate entries using where clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database:

test1 which looks like:

```
ID   pubmed_ID
-------------------
1    22
2    22
```

test2 looks like:

```
antigen    pubmed_ID
------------------
Hello      22
Bye        22
```

when i use the following select statment:

```
select * 
  from test1, test2 
 where test1.pubmed_ID = test2.pubmed_ID;
```

I get:

```
ID pubmed_ID antigen pubmed_ID
--------------------------------
1  22        Hello   22   
2  22        Hello   22   
1  22        Bye     22       
2  22        Bye     22
```

Why have the antigens been duplicated? When they only exist once in the test2 table?

The primary keys are as follows test1 = "ID" column and for test 2 both the "antigen" and "pubmed_ID" form a compund primary key

Am i missing something simple here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both are matches.  Which do you expect it to pick?

All the rows have the same `pubmed_ID`.  Thus, each row of `test1` matches each row of `test2`, so there are four (2*2) rows in the joined table.

Comment: How would i select against the "double" matches?

Comment: @Harpal, which of the 4 do you want?

Comment: @Harpal, but why those?  How should MySQL determine it?

Comment: Because ID "1" corresponds to Antigen "hello" and "2" corresponds to "bye"

Comment: Then maybe you need to add an `ID` field to to `test2` so you can join on that.  It's hard to tell if that makes sense.  You haven't given much data or info about your schema.

Comment: Hmmm ok back to the drawing board for my schema, thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's because two records in `test2` match per record in `test1`, based on the join criteria.

If you want it to be more selective, you need to add criteria that filters how you'd like.

Comment: Failing that, SELECT DISTINCT should help.

Comment: @Kalium: Based on the data in the example, DISTINCT wouldn't help because of the ID value - it's different per set of the other values.

Comment: Indeed it is. This is just straight data pollution, then.

Answer (score 1):

Your join is operating as it should.  You are matching pumed_ID which is the same for every row.

When the DBE grabs row 1 from table test1

```
ID   pubmed_ID
-------------------
1    22
```

And then matches to rows with the same pubmed_ID in table test2, both rows match...

```
antigen    pubmed_ID
------------------
Hello      22
Bye        22
```

The exact same thing happens with the second row from table test1, making the entire result set contain four rows.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, the test1.ID = 1 matches, through it's pubmed_ID both Hello and Bye, and the same for the other test1 record.